# How CBV DetailView will paginated

Tags: django, pagination, django-class-based-views

I have model:

```
class Lesson(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    lessoncontent = RichTextField()
    category = models.ForeignKey(CategoryLesson)
```

and view:

```
class LessonDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Lesson
    paginate_by = 1
    template_name = 'lessons/lesson_detail.html'
```

And also have ListView for a listing lessons

How i can paginate my lessons such as - 
**<<< Previous lesson | Next lesson >>>** ?

Comment: `DetailView` is for a single object, not for a set of objects. You need `ListView`.

Answer (score 1):

Calling it pagination is the mistake you are doing. For each Location, you want to be able to navigate to previous and next locations based on some criteria. Add two methods to your Location model - one for previous and one for next - which return the appropriate entries.

Refer to this code from Mezzanine cms which gets previous and next based on publish date - https://github.com/stephenmcd/mezzanine/blob/master/mezzanine/core/models.py#L243

Corresponding template code - https://github.com/stephenmcd/mezzanine/blob/master/mezzanine/blog/templates/blog/blog_post_detail.html#L91

```
{% block blog_post_previous_next %}
<ul class="pager">
{% with blog_post.get_previous_by_publish_date as previous %}
{% if previous %}
<li class="previous">
    <a href="{{ previous.get_absolute_url }}">&larr; {{ previous }}</a>
</li>
{% endif %}
{% endwith %}
{% with blog_post.get_next_by_publish_date as next %}
{% if next %}
<li class="next">
    <a href="{{ next.get_absolute_url }}">{{ next }} &rarr;</a>
</li>
{% endif %}
{% endwith %}
</ul>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Thx big for your answer! i will try it and write results here later

Comment: maybe are there more easier way? because here written in Note https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/pagination/ that Paginate can work with any objects, thats have Count

Comment: Raido, you're just confusing yourself by using the term "pagination", because what you're trying to achieve is not a pagination in the sense used in Django documentation. Pagination is for distributing a list of objects (returned by a `ListView`) over several pages; what you want is just two links which point to a next/previous page.

Comment: You need to define what is "next" and "previous" in this case, by selecting an attribute which will determine the sort order. In manojlds's example it's `published_date`, but it can be something else -- special ordering number (e.g. lesson 1, lesson 2 etc) or simply the name of the lesson.

Comment: wow! your answers realy directs me in right way :)) and now i`ll understand what need to do

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way would be to use ListView instead of DetailView.